# Batch file - Abc123 is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a script which takes user input details using 'set /p' then runs through a series of commands.

When running the script from a shortcut, it works fine, however when running directly from the command prompt, I get 'Abc123 is not recognised as an internal or external command', where 'abc123' is the user input for each of the 'set /p' commands.

If you press enter again at this point, it will move onto the next 'set /p' but never stores the value.

I can't figure out what's wrong here!

Comment: Neither can we as you haven't shown any code...

Comment: When running from the command line are you in the directory containing the script? If not try it from there.

Comment: Sorry, this is a fairly confidential environment so I won't be able to post any code. I can post snippets but I'm not sure how helpful that would be. And yes, I am in the directory at the time. It's just strange that it runs fine from a shortcut!

Comment: Could you post at least some lines around the set /p statemant?

Comment: The script is trying to run abc123, so at some point it's trying to execute what the user provides as input. This is absolutely a code-related issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scenario possibly reproducing your problem sufficiently and giving hints to resolve it either by "quoting" or via [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
==>30122435.bat

==>set "passw=xyz|abc123"

==>echo quoted  percent "xyz|abc123"
quoted  percent "xyz|abc123"

==>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

==>echo unquoted exclam. !passw!
unquoted exclam. xyz|abc123

==>echo unquoted percent xyz  | abc123
'abc123' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

==>type 30122435.bat
@ECHO ON
set "passw=xyz|abc123"
echo quoted  percent "%passw%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo unquoted exclam. !passw!
echo unquoted percent %passw%

==>
```